# Disable touchpad unless touch starts in centre

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

My laptop has a rather large touchpad, making it hard to reach all the keys without my palm accidentally touching the edge of it. What I would like to do is to keep the touchpad disabled unless I start my touch at the centre of it, is that possible?

The laptop in question is a Razer Blade.

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50216311/disabling-touchpad-on-ubuntu-18-04-temporarily

Comment: I was hoping it could be done automatically. Toggling the touchpad on and off manually gets a bit tedious